# Bootstrap modal is not showing in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-modal

I'm creating a login page which is based on PHP, I'm trying to make that if there is a server error, a modal will show up. But when I try to do this, an error shows up in the console that says

> '$' is not defined

How to make the modal show?

I tried to check if the code actually runs, and it is running.

**The modal in the file:**

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="server-error" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="server-error" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Server error</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Server error, Please contact AlexDorian7.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The code in PHP:**

```
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">showServerErrorMessage()</script>';
}
```

**The code in Javascript:**

```
function showServerErrorMessage() {
    $('#server-error').modal('show');
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "'$' is not defined" means that you are trying to use jquery functions (selector in this case) when jquery isn't available/found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do check if you have all the script and css related to bootstrap

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function showServerErrorMessage() {
        $("#server-error").modal('show');
    }
</script>
```

**call the function after defining it above**

```
<?php if ($conn->connect_error) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript"> showServerErrorMessage(); </script>
<?php } ?>
```

**you can put your model anywhere in page**

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-xl" id="server-error" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="server-error" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Server error</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Server error, Please contact AlexDorian7.
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I changed the so its without echo, and the jquery link was below the code, I moved it up. Thanks for the answer!